# Selecting records from the past three months

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables from which i need to run a query to display number of views a user had in the last 3 months from now.

So far I have come up with: all the field types are correct.

```
 SELECT dbo_LU_USER.USERNAME
 , Count(*) AS No_of_Sessions
 FROM dbo_SDB_SESSION 
   INNER JOIN dbo_LU_USER 
     ON dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_USERID = dbo_LU_USER.PK_USERID
 WHERE (((DateDiff("m",[dbo_SDB_SESSION].[SESSIONSTART],Now()))=0 
   Or (DateDiff("m",[dbo_SDB_SESSION].[SESSIONSTART],Now()))=1 
   Or (DateDiff("m",[dbo_SDB_SESSION].[SESSIONSTART],Now()))=2))
 GROUP BY dbo_LU_USER.USERNAME;
```

Basically, the code above display a list of all records within the past 3 months; however, it starts from the 1st day of the month and ends on the current date, but I need it to start 3 months prior to today's date.

Also to let you know this is SQL View in MS Access 2007 code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, basically the code above display a list of all records within the past 3 mmonths, however it starts of from the 1st day of the month and ends on current date, but I need it to start 3 months prior to todays date.

Comment: i don't know much about ms access, but in a simplified manner, you can think of this as running three separate questions (one more for each 'or'), and merging the results. it should be considerably quicker to do a `DateAdd("m", -3, Now())` (or however you get 'today minus three months' in ms access) and just make a compare to check that `sessionstart` is greater than that.

Comment: @Khalid: when i wrote my comment, i thought it was just that, a comment. but now that i read your comment, i'd add that what i've commented would also be the solution to your problem =)

Comment: Keep in mind that there's more than one interpretation of the common-language phrase "three months ago" -- is it the same date as today, just 3 months earlier? Is it 3 * 28 days ago? Is it the first day of the third month ago? If so, is that complete months, or counting the last one partially? Users may think it's clear to request that, but you really need to figure out exactly which dates they expect to see before you commit to an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how "strictly" you define your 3 months rule, you could make things a lot easier and probably efficient, by trying this:

```
SELECT dbo_LU_USER.USERNAME, Count(*) AS No_of_Sessions 
FROM dbo_SDB_SESSION 
INNER JOIN dbo_LU_USER 
ON dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_USERID = dbo_LU_USER.PK_USERID 
WHERE [dbo_SDB_SESSION].[SESSIONSTART] between now() and DateAdd("d",-90,now())
GROUP BY dbo_LU_USER.USERNAME;
```

(Please understand that my MS SQL is a bit rusty, and can't test this at the moment: the idea is to make the query scan all record whose date is between "TODAY" and "TODAY-90 days").

Comment: i think you could get a performance improvement by changing `between now() and ` to simply `>`, since access will otherwise do two checks, i.e. for both boundaries. since sessionstart will never be in the future, you only need to check the `> -90` part, not the `< now()`

Comment: That's yet another interpretation of 3 months, i.e., 90 days ago!